# Process the multithreading in trigger

Tags: multithreading, oracle, triggers

I have to generate number_order in table Transaction for each row (order is: 1, 2, 3...).

My solution is create a trigger before insert for table Transaction. Trigger's mission is count total rows of table `(select count(1) to v_count from Transaction)` --> then `set :new.num_order = v_count + 1`.

That solution runs ok for almost case, but when system has many many threads insert to table, trigger's executed by multi-threading and they return SAME ORDER (reason is the select command is called same time & before insert).
Can you advise me a replace solution for this. Thank you in advance.

**PS**: I am using oracle 12c database. And I can't use sequence because the order in fact base on some other columns in table (eg: `Room_id`). So the full select command is:

`select count(1) to v_count from transaction where room_id = :new.room_id`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is a bad approach that will lead to significant performance, scaling, and support issues.  I would rethink the design.

If you want to do this, you would need to force your transactions to serialize.  You could have a separate table with a primary key of `room_id` and a `room_count` value or you could add that column to `room`.  You would need to lock the row for the `room_id` via a `select for update`.  Then you would update the `room_count` and use that for your `insert`.  The lock would be released when your transaction commits.

If you do this, however, every other transaction that involves the same `room_id` will block.  If you have relatively short transactions, that may not be terrible assuming you don't have too many users working with the same room.  As the number of users and the length of transactions increase, however, the issues get much harder.  If transactions can involve multiple rooms, you'd need every transaction to process them in the same order (i.e. in `room_id` order for example) to avoid potential deadlocks.  If you are going to do something similar with more than just this table, things get even more complicated.

I would much rather use a sequence and then generate the sequential values in a query.  For example

```
SELECT room_id,
       rank() over (partition by room_id order by sequence_column) your_num_order
  FROM your_table
```

Or you could use the `sequence_column` for the initial insert and have a background job that periodically (daily is common) and assigns the `num_order` in a batch after the transactions are complete.

Comment: Thank you so much. But this solution seems complex for me.

Comment: @Khoa, the solution is complex because the hidden traps behind your requirements are complex.

Answer (score -1):

I'll propose following solution:
new table

```
create table  room_count( room_id NUMBER primary key,  cnt number);
```

Function to increment the count in an autonomous transaction:

```
Create or replace function inc_room_cnt( p_room_id NUMBER) return number as 
PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
  v_cnt NUMBER;
begin
  update room_count set cnt = cnt +1 where room_id = p_room_id returning cnt into v_cnt;

  -- insert new room if not yet exists
  if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then 
    v_cnt := 1;
    insert into room_count values (p_room_id, v_cnt);
  end if;

  commit;
  return v_cnt;
end;
/
```

in the `before insert` trigger you can call the `inc_room_cnt` to set the order:

```
:new.room_order := int_room_cnt(:new.room_id);
```